# Javascript animating CSS opacity, stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to animate a single elements opacity when I hover over it by using the same class and accessing it via $this.

I know I could solve this problem by adding different named classes for each item, but as my application grows that will not be a viable solution, below is my code, it currently animates all three image opacitys to 1.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".videos").hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
        $focus = $this.find('.video');
        $focus.stop().animate({opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
    }, function(){
        $(".video").stop().animate({opacity: 0.6 }, 500);
    });
});
</script>
```

And here is the html :

```
<div class="videos">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <h3>LATEST VIDEOS</h3>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span4 video1">
                        <a href="#"><img class="video" src="images/media/vid1.jpg"/></a>
                        <p>A description of the video will go here for the user to see,
                        once a user clicks a video the player will be enlarged and the other
                        videos shall be forced underneath</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 video2">
                        <a href="#"><img class="video" src="images/media/vid2.jpg"/></a>
                        <p>A description of the video will go here for the user to see,
                        once a user clicks a video the player will be enlarged and the other
                        videos shall be forced underneath</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="span4 video3">
                        <a href="#"><img class="video" src="images/media/vid3.jpg"/></a>
                        <p>A description of the video will go here for the user to see,
                        once a user clicks a video the player will be enlarged and the other
                        videos shall be forced underneath</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have tried browsing other web sources but I have not yet found a solution, I'm sure I have made a silly mistake somewhere.

Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant to bind the hover event to `$('.video')`, not `$('.videos')` (the wrapper).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".video").hover(function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 1.0 }, 500);
    }, function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity: 0.6 }, 500);
    });
});
</script>
```